# postfix high availability and scalability

Tags: mysql, postfix, docker, dovecot

i have successfully set up a postfix , dovecot , mysql container .i can receive and send emails through this container and every thing is going alright.now i am thinking about high availabilty and scalabilty.how to build a high available postfix , dovecot and mysql dockerized system? and how to scale up this system ?

Thanks

Comment: It's premature to talk about HA, etc; come back after you have sent 10K emails.  By then you will have some feel for the scaling needed.  Also, dba.stackexchange.com is a better place for MySQL discussions.